# How to convert comma-separated string to cell array of strings in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have following string

'A, B, C, D'

from which I want to make a cell array such as

{ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }

How would I be able to do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that will cut up the string at commas, semicolons, or white spaces, and that will work for strings of any length

```
string = 'A, BB, C'

tmp = regexp(string,'([^ ,:]*)','tokens');
out = cat(2,tmp{:})


out = 

    'A'    'BB'    'C'
```

Answer (score 3):

For your specific example try:

```
cellstr(strread('A, B, C, D','%c,'))'
```

Answer (score 3):

a more simple way:  t1 = strsplit('A, B, C, D', ',');