# Parse the cell array into different cells

Tags: matlab

I would like to parse

```
A,B,4,C,D,E,F
E3,E4,4,RE,RT,EW,TR
```

which are loaded into Matlab in 2*1 cells. I would like to have them in different cells which should look like 2*7 cell.

The first cell is filled into a cell 1*7 and second is filled into next cell of type 1*7.

Comment: Is that first line a comma separated string, stored in a single cell? If so, then this is a duplicate of [how-to-convert-comma-separated-string...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535821/how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-cell-array-of-strings-in-matlab). Let me know if I've got the problem wrong. Cheers.

Comment: @user1494754 can you give an example of the content of some of those <2x1> cells?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to have been abandoned; an answer was found but not added.

Answer (score 1):

Given a bunch of 2x1 cell arrays in Matlab, for example:

```
X1 = {'A'; 'B'};    
X2 = {'4'; 'C'};
X3 = {'D'; 'E'};
X4 = {'F'; 'E3'};
X5 = {'E4'; '4'};
X6 = {'RE'; 'RT'};
X7 = {'EW'; 'TR'};
```

Then you can use basic array operations to concatenate them, providing the dimensions match:

```
>> X = [X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7]

X = 

'A'    '4'    'D'    'F'     'E4'    'RE'    'EW'
'B'    'C'    'E'    'E3'    '4'     'RT'    'TR'
```

Comment: this is not I am looking for. But anyways thanks. I sorted it out