# How to convert Matlab string CSV of cell into separate columns of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix, cell

If I have a  Matlab CELL line of string characters separated by a comma like:

```
12/28/2012,00:00:01,0.99458,1,10518,0.99458,0.99483,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,b,-,C
```

How do I separate each one into its own column within a matrix? What is the most efficient way of doing this? 
Can this be done? 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert comma-separated string to cell array of strings in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535821/how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-cell-array-of-strings-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Just realized this question duplicates [how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-cell-array-of-strings-in-matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535821/how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-cell-array-of-strings-in-matlab) and that my answer duplicates the answer provided by @Jonas. I'm flagging it as a duplicate.

Here is the most efficient method I'm aware of:

```
%# Build your string
Input = '12/28/2012,00:00:01,0.99458,1,10518,0.99458,0.99483,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,b,-,C';

%# Convert to cell array of strings
Output = regexp(Input, '([^,]*)', 'tokens');
Output = cat(2, Output{:});
```

Some points to note:

1) Note, this will work whether `Input` is a character array (ie a string) or a cell containing a character array.

2) I've assumed you want the output to be a cell array of strings. Offhand, I can't think of another way of grouping strings of differing length into separate columns using Matlab without building your own custom class.

3) The solution provided by @IlyaKobelevskiy will group the strings into separate rows (not columns) and thus essentially limits you to only a single observation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming str is your cell line:

```
str ={'12/28/2012,00:00:01,0.99458,1,10518,0.99458,0.99483,0,0,0,0,-,-,-,b,-,C'};
ind=strfind(str{1},',');
len=diff([0 ind]);
sz=max(len);
A=zeros(length(ind),sz);
prev=1;
for i=1:length(ind)
    A(i,1:len(i)-1)=str{1}(prev:(ind(i)-1));
    prev=ind(i)+1;
end;
A=char(A);
```

Not sure if it is the most efficient way, but should work...